# Alternative for "I have to mention that"

Tags: word-choice

I am writing an article. I have repeated  "I have to mention that" several times in my article. What is  alternatives for "I have to mention that"?

Comment: Why not just take it out?

Comment: I think this is "Writing Advice" rather than "English for Learners". You could ring the changes with *It's worth noting, Bear in mind, We must remember,* etc. But as @zondo says, perhaps the best advice is simply to tell your reader whatever it is you've got to say, and don't waste his precious attention *telling* him that you're going to say something.

Comment: Why are you writing it in the first place?

Comment: I must agree with FumbleFingers. Since you are the author of the article who else would be mentioning the various tidbits? Think of superfluous words as noise hiding your message.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to use such things when I want to keep the attention of the reader when I am giving additional information. That should not happen several times in an article. My suggestions:

- It's worth mentioning ...
- I should point out that ...
- Let us not forget ...
- Notice that ...